# Unknown module(s) in QT: core

Tags: c++, qt, include

I'm having a lot of trouble with Qt. When I try to build my project (imported from another PC) I get the error:

`Unknown module(s) in QT: core`

Moreover, I have a `No such file or directory` error whenever I make an `#include <Q*>` (* meaning String, or Widget...)

If anyone has had this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you that the Qt folder is set in your path ?

Comment: It is set yes, the Qt/%version%

Comment: Try `Qt/5.4.1/msvc_2013` // or what version you really have

Comment: Same result, I really don't get why it doesn't know where its own libraries are

Comment: *imported from another PC* - Have you installed Qt on the machine with which you're trying to build the project and can you compile other Qt projects?

Comment: Yes I have, and No I can't build any otther Qt projects, even made with their wizard, same problem

Comment: How did you install Qt? Did you use the installer? Did you move it around after installation? (don't do that)

Comment: Haha no I did not move it, and yes, i launched the installer, and installed everything. I guess I can try reinstalling it

Comment: Did you copy the build directory? Did you copy a `.pro.user` file in the project directory? (you must not do that)

Comment: Well to be honest I cloned the repo, which had the `.pro.user` file in it...

Comment: @JoColina `.pro.user` files as per-machine configurations that should not be checked-in. Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me on Debian: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70887187/350875

In other words, installing the package `qtbase5-dev`.