# Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui quick

Tags: qt, debian, qmake

I installed Pop!_OS 21.04 (based on Ubuntu Hirsute), and I'm trying to build a QML app I programmed on FreeBSD. qmake doesn't make the project, complaining that:

```
error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core gui quick
```

I installed Qt Creator through `apt`.

KDE works fine, so does LXQt. Flatpak Qt Creator also works.

The same issue happens on Debian, so I'm assuming it'll happen in every Debian-based OS.

Comment: execute:  `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

Comment: Doesn't work. `State: Not a real package (virtual)`.

Comment: The problem is that you installed only IDE, without actual Qt. Find Qt package for your system and install it.

Comment: KDE works fine, that's the other thing...

Comment: I have Qt and all of the QML modules you can get with apt.

Comment: Same issue on a clean LXQt Debian install.

Comment: Debian 11: sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev

Answer (score 13):

This is the solution that worked from above comments:
Per @Egg:

> Debian 11: sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev